# Removing More Than Two Duplicates From A List

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I'm trying to figure out the best way to remove duplicates from a list in C#. However I want to keep two of the duplicated entries (two total identical entries) while removing all of the rest. I've seen plenty of examples of removing all duplicates from a list, but my specific issue seems to be less common.

This is the majority of my code. The background is this is a debate scheduler project for a class I'm in. I research a few ways to delete duplicates and found many on here but not with my stipulations. Each team can only debate twice per day and no more and they are assigned randomly to there debate times leading to my problem of them being assigned more than two times per scheduled day.

The teams are being assigned randomly and then moved to a list, so by duplicates I mean I'm trying to remove all dupes after the initial two if they exist at all.

Thanks and sorry for the ambiguity.

```
namespace SWEProject3
{
public partial class DebateSchedulerForm : Form
{
    //There are 10 slots for team names
    //The names can only be edited by the superadmin

    static int ADMIN = 1;
    static int GUEST = 2;

    public List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> winList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> lossList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> dateList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> debateList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> week1List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week2List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week3List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week4List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week5List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week6List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week7List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week8List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week9List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> week10List = new List<string>();

    public DebateSchedulerForm(int x)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initNames();
        initWin();
        initLoss();
        initDates();
        initDebates();
        initWeekLists();
        ListNames();
        ListWin();
        ListLoss();
        ListDates();


        if (x == ADMIN || x == GUEST)
        {
            Name1.ReadOnly = true;
            Name2.ReadOnly = true;
            Name3.ReadOnly = true;
            Name4.ReadOnly = true;
            Name5.ReadOnly = true;
            Name6.ReadOnly = true;
            Name7.ReadOnly = true;
            Name8.ReadOnly = true;
            Name9.ReadOnly = true;
            Name10.ReadOnly = true;

            Win1.ReadOnly = true;
            Win2.ReadOnly = true;
            Win3.ReadOnly = true;
            Win4.ReadOnly = true;
            Win5.ReadOnly = true;
            Win6.ReadOnly = true;
            Win7.ReadOnly = true;
            Win8.ReadOnly = true;
            Win9.ReadOnly = true;
            Win10.ReadOnly = true;

            Loss1.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss2.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss3.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss4.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss5.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss6.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss7.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss8.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss9.ReadOnly = true;
            Loss10.ReadOnly = true;

            ChangeDates.Visible = false;
            Save.Visible = false;
        }

    }
    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        int n = debateList.Count();
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = gen.Next(n + 1);
            string value = debateList[k];
            debateList[k] = debateList[n];
            debateList[n] = value;
        }
    }
    public void ListNames()
    {
        this.Name1.Text = nameList[0];
        this.Name2.Text = nameList[1];
        this.Name3.Text = nameList[2];
        this.Name4.Text = nameList[3];
        this.Name5.Text = nameList[4];
        this.Name6.Text = nameList[5];
        this.Name7.Text = nameList[6];
        this.Name8.Text = nameList[7];
        this.Name9.Text = nameList[8];
        this.Name10.Text = nameList[9];
    }
    public void ListWin()
    {
        this.Win1.Text = winList[0];
        this.Win2.Text = winList[1];
        this.Win3.Text = winList[2];
        this.Win4.Text = winList[3];
        this.Win5.Text = winList[4];
        this.Win6.Text = winList[5];
        this.Win7.Text = winList[6];
        this.Win8.Text = winList[7];
        this.Win9.Text = winList[8];
        this.Win10.Text = winList[9];
    }
    public void ListLoss()
    {
        this.Loss1.Text = lossList[0];
        this.Loss2.Text = lossList[1];
        this.Loss3.Text = lossList[2];
        this.Loss4.Text = lossList[3];
        this.Loss5.Text = lossList[4];
        this.Loss6.Text = lossList[5];
        this.Loss7.Text = lossList[6];
        this.Loss8.Text = lossList[7];
        this.Loss9.Text = lossList[8];
        this.Loss10.Text = lossList[9];
    }
    public void ListDates()
    {
        this.Date1.Text = dateList[0];
        this.Date2.Text = dateList[1];
        this.Date3.Text = dateList[2];
        this.Date4.Text = dateList[3];
        this.Date5.Text = dateList[4];
        this.Date6.Text = dateList[5];
        this.Date7.Text = dateList[6];
        this.Date8.Text = dateList[7];
        this.Date9.Text = dateList[8];
        this.Date10.Text = dateList[9];
    }
    public void initNames()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("nameList.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            nameList.Add(line);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
    public void initWin()
    {
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader("Win.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string line = sw.ReadLine();
            winList.Add(line);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void initLoss()
    {
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader("Loss.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string line = sw.ReadLine();
            lossList.Add(line);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void initDates()
    {
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader("Dates.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string line = sw.ReadLine();
            dateList.Add(line);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void initDebates()
    {
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader("Debate.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
        {
            string line = sw.ReadLine();
            debateList.Add(line);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void initWeekLists()
    {

        week1List.Add(debateList[0]);
        week1List.Add(debateList[1]);
        week1List.Add(debateList[2]);
        week1List.Add(debateList[3]);
        week1List.Add(debateList[4]);

        week2List.Add(debateList[5]);
        week2List.Add(debateList[6]);
        week2List.Add(debateList[7]);
        week2List.Add(debateList[8]);
        week2List.Add(debateList[9]);

        week3List.Add(debateList[10]);
        week3List.Add(debateList[11]);
        week3List.Add(debateList[12]);
        week3List.Add(debateList[13]);
        week3List.Add(debateList[14]);

        week4List.Add(debateList[15]);
        week4List.Add(debateList[16]);
        week4List.Add(debateList[17]);
        week4List.Add(debateList[18]);
        week4List.Add(debateList[19]);

        week5List.Add(debateList[20]);
        week5List.Add(debateList[21]);
        week5List.Add(debateList[22]);
        week5List.Add(debateList[23]);
        week5List.Add(debateList[24]);

        week6List.Add(debateList[25]);
        week6List.Add(debateList[26]);
        week6List.Add(debateList[27]);
        week6List.Add(debateList[28]);

        week7List.Add(debateList[29]);
        week7List.Add(debateList[30]);
        week7List.Add(debateList[31]);
        week7List.Add(debateList[32]);

        week8List.Add(debateList[33]);
        week8List.Add(debateList[34]);
        week8List.Add(debateList[35]);
        week8List.Add(debateList[36]);

        week9List.Add(debateList[37]);
        week9List.Add(debateList[38]);
        week9List.Add(debateList[39]);
        week9List.Add(debateList[40]);

        week10List.Add(debateList[41]);
        week10List.Add(debateList[42]);
        week10List.Add(debateList[43]);
        week10List.Add(debateList[44]);

    }
    public void finNames()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("nameList.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name1.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name2.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name3.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name4.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name5.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name6.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name7.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name8.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name9.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Name10.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void finWin()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Win.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win1.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win2.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win3.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win4.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win5.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win6.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win7.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win8.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win9.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Win10.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void finLoss()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Loss.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss1.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss2.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss3.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss4.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss5.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss6.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss7.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss8.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss9.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(this.Loss10.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }
    public void finDebates()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Debate.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(debateList[i]);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finNames();
        finWin();
        finLoss();
        finDebates();
    }

    private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ChangeDates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeDates form = new ChangeDates(dateList);
        form.ShowDialog();
        initDates();
        ListDates();
    }

    private void Date1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Week_1 form = new Week_1(nameList, week1List);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Date2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Week_2 form = new Week_2(nameList, week2List);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried showing what type of list and example data.

Comment: Do you want to keep entries that only occurs once?

Comment: Please narrow down your code to only what matters. That is a lot of code to read through.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `debateList` is the list you'd like to filter:

```
public List<string> debateList = new List<string>();
```

You can use Linq's [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method chained with the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and take advantage of the [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which will take up to the max specified even if less are present:

```
List<string> result = debateList.GroupBy( x => x )
                                .SelectMany( x => x.Take( 2 ) )
                                .OrderBy( x => x )
                                .ToList()
```

Comment: This is better than my answer, I really should read a book on Linq!

Comment: @Ashigore - you had a good answer (I was actually refining my answer as you posted yours); it just needed to go through a couple of refactors :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a counting variable, loop through the container and increment the counter each time an element is present in the container.